# 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

After updating the RN version from 0.70.6 to 0.71.4 ios pod install working, but the app doesn't build and gives an error.
'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
any ideas??

I have tried all steps in react-native-update-helper(android works)

**Updated**

I don't have AppDelegate.mm so i did all changes in AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` it has to come before `use_react_native`.

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true # if you're using firebase

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
deployment_target = '13.0'
prepare_react_native_project!
# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'AppName' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  # This has to come before use_react_native or you get AppDelegate or RCTEventEmitter not found
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

end
````

Also I am on Mac M1, and I **am not excluding arm64**. In my Project -> Target -> Exclude Architectures, I am only excluding i386 for both Debug and Release. Excluding arm64 caused issues with finding certain files as well. I hope something works!

Another well known issue is if you're also using react-native-splash-screens it will cause your iOS entrypoint to hang for 0.71.0 and greater. Update your AppDelegate.mm like so

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure]; // If you're using react-native firebase

  self.moduleName = @"main";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  bool didFinish = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   
   [RNSplashScreen show];  // this needs to be called after [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   
   return didFinish;
}
```

for android the builds were fine, but if you still want to open the splash screen follow the installation instructions and add `import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;` to the import statements, then add this to the bottom of MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(null); // to ensure android is compatible with react-native-screens
  }

} // This is the final closing bracket of public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you opened "projectName".xcworkspace and not "projectName".xcodeproj in XCode.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**

I had started building the app on Windows and testing on Android. I wanted to test on iOS as well, so I moved the code to my Intel Mac running Monterey.

After following the [React Native Environment setup guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=ios), I stumbled upon this error when trying to build my app:

```
fatal error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
```

After hours of troubleshooting, I found that my Podfile in the *project\ios* folder was always generated empty.

```
> pod init
> pod install
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.
```

I tried creating a new ReactNative project with:

```
> npx react-native init TestProject
```

And it worked and built the app without any errors.

**Steps I ended up doing:**

1. Downgrading Ruby:

   ```
   > brew install rbenv ruby-build
   > rbenv install 2.7.6
   > eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
   ```
2. Creating a new ReactNative project to test if everything is working smoothly

   ```
   > npx react-native init TestProject
   ```
3. I noticed the *`pod --version`* command showed 1.8.3, even though I had a newer version installed. After uninstalling it using `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`, it still showed the same version. I had to uninstall all traces of Pod with this command:

   ```
   > which pod
   > sudo rm -rf <path>
   ```
4. Copied the Podfile contents of the TestProject to my main project and ran:

   ```
   > pod install
   ```

App built without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `Pods` and `build` folders and `Podfile.lock` file, then re-install pods.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting **ios/build** folder and reinstalling the dependencies. But I am not sure what caused this.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the node_modules folder, along with package-lock.json

then run npm cache clean --force

and the reinstall using npm install

if you are using yard, basicly the same thing, rm yarn.lock, yarn cache clean and then yarn install

Comment: i did not help. Again giving same error