# Pipeline runs successfully for dev scheme but fails for uat scheme. I get 'failed with exit code 65 in Azure Devops' error

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-pipelines

I get the below error when running the pipeline for UAT scheme, But the same works fine for dev scheme.

```
In file included from /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/ExComm/AppDelegate.mm:1:
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/ExComm/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

note: Run script build phase '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
note: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
note: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
note: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'ExCommUat' from project 'ExComm')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ayrfjsjvvrrjiw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/zzz.build/Release-iphoneos/Et.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/ExComm/AppDelegate.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Uat' from project 'Project')
(1 failure)
##[debug]Exit code 65 received from tool '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'

##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 65
```

Comment: May I know if your UAT and Dev schemes are using the same agent to build? Anyway, please try the suggestions mentioned in the similar thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75822104/rctappdelegate-h-file-not-found to see if that helps.

Comment: Also try to add a command line task to run the commands mentioned here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36611#issuecomment-1552463986 (`npm install, remove pod, remove pod.lock` etc) before the build step to see if it works.